# JavaScript regex to validate an input is more than 0 characters

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Forgive me if this is super simple, but I googled and googled and couldn't find a good example. I'm not that great with regex and just need to valid that an input has more than 1 character (i.e. is not blank). I'm using Angular ng-pattern.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-pattern="/regex/">
```

I need to verify that there as something in the input (not empty). I've used a couple of example, but the issue is once you clear the input, angular is still seeing the pattern as valid. I need it to fail once the input is empty again, but not on first load. As always all help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I basically need a regex that will verify the field is not blank. Here is a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/izFl61v7ANVj46hbuM5o?p=preview)

Comment: `/.{1,}/`, or even just `/./` should match anything but an empty string

Comment: Do you have a fiddle the represents the issue?

Comment: @David there is a plnkr link in the descrition in the EDIT section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `required` for that:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" name="username" required>
```

See this pluckr fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/VwY1WPdCocKHwww69ZSj?p=preview

More in the docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input#usage_parameters

If you REALLY want to use `ng-pattern` you should add start/end of input (`^` and `$`):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="username" ng-pattern="/^$/">
```

But remember, this will **validate** a blank input (the input value matches the pattern).

Comment: Thanks @David. This is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate it.

Comment: for the Angular 7/8 required allows the user to type empty strings. do you know to validate to make sure the input isn't just empty spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Use `/.+/` (`.` means every possible character (except from new line characters and `+` means at least once)

Comment: I tried that. The problem is when you clear the input (i.e. it's not an empty string) that still counts as valid. I basically need a regex that verifies the field is not blank.

Comment: `/[^\s]/` will match anything, but not empty spaces

Comment: @adeneo sorry same effect. angular still see the empty field as valid