# How to disallow space using ng-pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ng-pattern

I have belopw ng-pattern set in one of my form field. It gives validation error on field if user enters non numeric value. If i just put empty string and validate, it doesnot show any validation error on field. How can i check if my field is empty using ng-pattern below.

```
ng-pattern="/^(\+|-)?(?:180(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/"
```

Comment: You could just add the `required` attribute to the input: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503193/javascript-regex-to-validate-an-input-is-more-than-0-characters)

Comment: @RyanWilson- thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. :)